# Using an XSL Element (?) as a URL in an <a> tag in Symphony CMS

Tags: xml, xslt, symphony-cms

I have just started trying to get my head around Symphony and XML/XSL based templating etc (I don't even know the correct terminology so forgive me).

I have a Videos section in Symphony, and one of the Input fields is for a YouTube URL. I obviously can't just write `<a href="<xsl:value-of select="youtube-url"/>">Video</a>` but I'm really not sure how it SHOULD be done.

I did some Googling and found that xml/xsl or whatever supports variables so I thought that was a good shout, but as you can see in my code example below, whatever I have done, it has failed. Maybe I'm just using variables wrong? I don't know.

I just need my Youtube-URL to be in the space that I currently have {$youtube}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:include href="../utilities/master.xsl"/>
<xsl:variable name="youtube"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="youtube-url"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="data">
    <div class="video-container">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="videos/entry"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="videos/entry">
    <div class="video">
        <div class="video-title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></div>
        <div class="video-player">
            {$youtube}
        </div>
        <div class="video-desc"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you update your question and include your input XML (either the entire document or a useful snippet)?. Then I am sure your question can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write

```
<a href="<xsl:value-of select="youtube-url"/>">Video</a>
```

but you can write

```
<a href="{youtube-url}">Video</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{$youtube}">Video</a>
```

That's an *attribute value template*.

It only works in within attributes, though. You cannot use it in other text. (something like `<div class="video-player">{$youtube}</div>` will not work - use `<xsl:value-of>` instead.)

Comment: Woah man. You've blown my mind. I read that somewhere else, and stupidly I tested it by just pasting in {youtube-url}, which just outputted {youtube-url}, but it works when its in the href attr. Thank you man! - footnote: I am using 'man' gender ambiguously.

Comment: Of course in your case the variant that outputs the `$youtube` variable doesn't make sense, as the variable contents is fixed.

Comment: I know what you mean. :)